# $templatecache and $routeprovider - 404

Tags: angularjs, templates, gruntjs

I am using the grunt task `grunt-angular-templates` for precompiling angular templates in my app, which has resulted in output like that:

```
$templateCache.put('src/ng-app/views/story/page.html',
  //...html
```

but this route is throwing a 404 on the template file

```
.when('/:pageId.aspx', {
   templateUrl:  'src/ng-app/views/story/page.html',
```

I've seen another post about setting the ID of the template and specifying that in the route but I don't know how to do that for external files - the example uses inline templates like that:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="login.html">
  login.html
</script>
```

Comment: Have you specified module name for templateCache and included it as a dependency in your app?

Comment: It's funny, because I have two apps on the go and I added this to one and not the other, seemed to make no difference. What made the difference was the order of the views script - had to be before I made the route declarations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution in the end - I had to ensure the view script generated by ngTemplates was included before route declarations (i have those in a separate script `routes.js`)

Its also key to ensure the module is the same in `ngTemplates` grunt:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp.Web'...

 ngtemplates:  {
        app: {
            src: 'src/ng-app/views/**/*.html',
            dest: 'dist/src/js/ng-views.js',
            options: {
                module: 'MyApp.Web'
            }
        }
    }
```

Adding templates as a dependency made no discernible difference (as I found on another post):

```
angular.module('templates', []);
var app = angular.module('MyApp.Web', [
    'ngRoute',
    'youtube-embed',
    'templates'
]);
```